# How to strip unwanted symbols from a static library or object file on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, static-libraries

Is there an equivalent of the GNU "strip" tool for Windows?

I'd like to strip out the names of any internal symbols from a static library, so that running `dumpbin /symbols mylib.lib` will no longer list the symbols with internal linkage.

On Linux, the `strip` command is typically used to do this. You can strip individual symbols by name, but also by type: running `strip --strip-unneeded libmylib.a` will remove any debuginfo sections from mylib.a's object files, as well as its internal symbols.